# Excel Go to special -> Blanks doesn't return any blank cells, why?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with a column which has nested `SUSTITUTE` functions to filter out free text remains from another column. The column is about 350 rows long, cells returning data are about 20 I think. Now I want to remove all cells which hasn't returned any data.

When I use the Go to special -> Blanks function which should select all the cells that don't contain any data and let me remove them, Excel returns no selection.

Please see images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Please note** I have tried copying the column and pasted **only the values** to a different column to see if Excel perceived `NULL` returning functions as not being blanks, but this returned the same error.

Can anyone with better Excel knowledge please try and help me with figuring out what I'm doing wrong?

Or have another approach to deleting the cells?

**My Excel version is 16.37 as part of MS Office 2016**

Comment: This behavior is also appear in excel for Windows, refer to this article: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/02/10/go-to-special-blanks-no-longer-my-go-to-guy/

Comment: @Lee oh? So the Go to Blanks is pretty much broken then?

Comment: Stumbling upon this myself right now - I've found that I can do text-to-columns on the offending columns and it works afterwards. Unfortunately that works for one column at a time and I have over a thousand - saving a copy of the file as a .csv (you will lose your formulas), closing the file, and re-opening the .csv file did the trick for me.